# Questions regarding legal aspects of John Oliver's debt forgiveness giveaway

Tags: united-states, tax-law, non-profit

John Oliver made news a few months ago by purchasing nearly $15 million in outstanding medical bill debt for $60,000 -- less than a penny on the dollar.

But, I read that cancellation-of-debt ("COD") is [taxable income](https://www.irs.gov/taxtopics/tc431.html).  How Oliver got around this ("...no tax consequences whatsoever...") seems odd...

Oliver set up a dummy corporation ("[CARP](http://www.centralassetrecoveryprofessionals.com/)") and then as CEO of CARP, he negotiated the debt purchase (presumably from some other collection agency).

But, rather than forgive the debt directly, CARP turned around and *donated* the debt to [RIP](https://www.ripmedicaldebt.org/), a charitable organization.

Am I to understand that this second transfer was *necessary* in order to **explicitly avoid** the tax consequence of COD?  I do understand that [COD is taxable income](http://www.natlawreview.com/article/tax-consequences-john-oliver-s-15-million-medical-debt-forgiveness), but "gifts" are not.

CARP is a simple [$50 setup-fee LLC](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/form-llc-how-to-organize-llc-30287.html) (and presumably *not* a charitable organization), whereas RIP was/is an established [501(c)(3)](https://www.irs.gov/charities-non-profits/charitable-organizations/exemption-requirements-section-501-c-3-organizations) charity.

I'm assuming that Once CARP purchased the debt, it then had rights of ownership with respect to debt collection, i.e. it could (1) continue pursuing collections from the debtors, (2) do nothing with the debt, (3) forgive the debts individually or *en masse*, or (4) donate it to a charity (which is what it did).  After CARP gave (donated) the debt to RIP, then RIP was free to forgive the debts (which is its [explicitly-stated mission](https://www.ripmedicaldebt.org/how-it-works/)).

Had CARP pursued option (3) above, then does that mean all that forgiven debt was/is taxable income as COD?

**ADDENDUM:**

I just now realized that, in a theoretical situation where CARP chose option (1) -- attempt to collect on the debt.  Pretending that CARP successfully collected e.g. $1 million, is this simply money that CARP can keep?  (Subject to corporate income tax, of course.)

I'm also assuming that "purchasing" debt gives the purchaser rights of ownership such that any collected money from a debtor cannot be further claimed by previous creditors.  Is this indeed the case?

Comment: For that matter, if this trick really works, it seems like nobody ever needs to pay income tax on cancelled debt again: just ask the creditor to donate your debt instead of cancelling it.  Seems like a suspiciously big loophole.

Comment: While I think this is an interesting topic, I'm having a hard time picking out *one* question here to answer. I see "was the second transfer necessary?", "if CARP pursued option 3 out of 4, is it taxable income?", "can CARP keep money?", and "does purchasing debt prevent previous creditors from collecting". Those are all interesting questions, but Stack Exchange works best if you have one question to answer and create new questions for the others.

Comment: The answer to the last question is surely yes - that is the whole point of purchasing debt, so that the buyer can collect instead of the seller.  It would be nonsensical if this caused the amount of the debt to double.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That was my thought, too.  But, as mentioned in the various articles I linked, the level of indebtedness presumes that the debtors are in dire straits financially--they don't appear to be "gaming" the system.

Comment: @pr1268: I don't doubt that, but I'm wondering why the same trick would not be available to those who *did* want to game the system.

Comment: @Thunderforge: Thanks for the feedback.  Yes, I tend to ramble sometimes, and I often ask questions on the various SE sites somewhat tangentially, but I'm trying to stimulate a discussion more than just get a simple answer.  That being said, time = money, and they're both a finite resource, so I'll work on tidying up my questions. :)

Comment: @pr1268 If you haven't already, check out [the site tour](http://law.stackexchange.com/tour). As it says, "This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum." I think rather than stimulate discussion as you said, this site is intended to stimulate interest in questions that people might not have previously considered. Clearly you've done that with the number of upvotes you have received! Just keep that in mind as you clean up the question and I'm sure it will continue to be well received, hopefully attracting a really great answer.

Comment: @NateEldredge "just ask the creditor to donate the debt" if I do that I may have a charitable donation (if every one agrees the value is the basis instead of the true zero value) but i dont see how to claim the loss as an operating cost. And if I'm sending you a 1099-C I am unlikely to take steps to reduce your tax on account of your asking.

Comment: @user662852: I see. By cancelling the debt, the creditor is able to deduct the full balance as a loss, which is valuable for them.  So CARP is giving up that deduction, but they don't care because they earn no profits anyway, and thus will pay no taxes.  This also explains how this scheme isn't really tax arbitrage: there's no taxable income to the debtor, but there's also no deduction for the creditor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oliver or his shell corporation could have directly forgiven the debt as a gift to the debtors. As a gift, it would not have to be reported as income, [according to the IRS](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/p4681.pdf). In that case, he would need to file [Form 709](https://www.irs.gov/instructions/i709/ch01.html#d0e256) and he would have to pay federal gift tax. There is an annual exclusion of $14,000 per donee, which probably is a drop in the bucket. It may not be required to pay tax on gifts to a 501(c)(3) organization, since the gift-bump is offset by the associated charitable gift deduction. The charity can then forgive the debt as a gift (and as tax-exempt, would not have to pay gift tax). In that sense, the second transfer was necessary, although it would not have been if RIP had directly obtained the debt (or if CARP were a 503(c)(3)).